# should I buy an amplifier or monitor PA for my electro acoustic guitar?

Tags: guitar, amplifiers

I have an Epiphone Masterbuilt, which has eSonic2™ preamp system, I was wondering if I should buy an amplifier or a monitor (PA system)... Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to the site. I've removed the "what brands are best" bit as we try to avoid evaluating specific brands/models - hope that's ok.

Comment: I play acoustic guitars with pickups in various situations.  When I do, I also sing so I need to be able to plug in my mic as well as guitar.  I sometimes use a full PA, sometimes use a powered monitor as a mini PA, and sometimes use my inexpensive Acoustic Amp that has two channels (one for instrument and one for mic) with separate controls for each.  I will post an answer later when I have more time to explain the advantages, disadvantages and potential uses for various solutions that I have personally used (and I have used tons of different systems).

Answer (score 2):

It may depend what else you want to do, now, or ultimately. There's hardly a need for an amp of any sort for home playing and practising with an acoustic guitar, whether it has pups or not. So I assume it's for playing in public. Merely playing the guitar, perhaps with others, an amp will do the trick. Especially an *acoustic guitar* amp.

However, if you sing as well, you're going to need an amp for that - and a mic - and an acoustic amp won't be as good as a p.a, which will also do a good job with the guitar.

There are many amps out there over the last few years which have been specially produced to be used as mini p.as, and guitar amps all rolled into one. And they do extremely well at both. Not cheap, but quality rarely comes that way.

Not recommending any brand - it's not company policy - but one of those would be a best bet, if you need more than just a guitar amp.

Incidentally,(as you mention p.a/monitor); a p.a system in its simplest form comprises mic., mixer, amp and speaker/s. 'Monitors' are an extra, so that the performers can hear better on stage. You could get away with a *powered monitor* for smaller gigs, instead of a p.a.